# Cannot activate geckodriver (Java-SELENIUM WebDriver)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am working on some basic selenium and i seem to have troubles with the browsers versions or the drivers, I had versions mismatch with chrome before but now i have tried to use FIREFOX and still i get a weird error from the console. i have also tried to search the site for a similiar accident but to no avail. below are my entire code and error stack(very small code).

I have checked that the browsers and the chromedriver and geckodriver are indeed the latest version. JARS for latest selenium are included ofcourse.

[entire code and stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk6I2.png)

Comment: Did you check for jars other than selenium related. Do you have any package like com/google/common/collect, if so check if there is any class as ImmutableMap?

Comment: I'd remove one of those Selenium libraries.  (You don't need both with and without source)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the selenium-server-standalone jar along with the selenium client jars to the buildpath should resolve this error.